# Integral of $(\log(z))^2dz$ over a line $C$ from $1$ to $i$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am lost, I don't know how to start. I need to evaluate

> $$\int_C (\log(z))^2dz $$
>   where $C$ is the line from $1$ to $i$.

Comment: What have you covered? Are you allowed to make use of Cauchy's theorem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of Cauchy's theorem, then note that $\log z$ and its square are analytic in the first quadrant away from $0$. By Cauchy's theorem, the integral depends only on the endpoints, not the path taken (provided the path stays within the same simply connected analytic region). Thus we can replace that straight-line path with one that is easier to compute. In particular, with the circle segment $z = e^i\theta$ for $0 \le \theta \le \pi / 2$. Make that substitution, and you will find this breaks into a pair of somewhat nasty but still workable real integrals.